# Can I be notified if a user presses the home button after I call startActivityForResult?

Tags: android

I'm using ZXing's `IntentIntegrator` to open a Barcode Scanner activity. If I use the back button to back out of the activity then `onActivityResult` still gets called with a `resultCode` other than `RESULT_OK`. However if I press the home button then `onActivityResult` is not called at all (maybe eventually when the activity is disposed of, but nowhere near immediately like I need).

I've tried adding flags to the intent that IntentIntegrator uses to open the scanner. I thought flags like `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` along with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` might force the activity to `finish` when the home button was pressed but regardless of if it finishes or not `onActivityResult` doesn't fire.

What kind of options do I have so I can be notified or poll and ask for when an Activity (that I didn't write and can't change) started by `startActivityForResult` is left because the user pressed the home button, opened another app from recents, opened an app from a notification they may have, or in any other way leave the started activity?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you press Home, the called activity isn't actually `finish()`ed; nor does it return back to the calling activity. This is expected behavior, as the called activity is still at the top of the backstack.

Anything you do to "fix" this would be going against basic Android functionality.

Comment: I am trying to go against basic Android functionality. I want to force my app to be responded to. It's a very persistent alarm clock app to get me up in the morning. I'm requiring myself to go and scan a qr code so I can then Snooze/Dismiss the alarm. If a user can open the scanner then press home to get out of it, then the alarm won't be snoozed OR dismissed and that's a problem.

Comment: Why not use a notification to allow the user to get back into your original activity? That's what Android's Alarm Clock app does.

Comment: The user may not want to get back to the original activity. I'm not a morning person. I'll paw at the thing until it shuts up and roll over not remembering anything. If my app doesn't receive an explicit Snooze or Dismiss action then it needs to persist.